# ROBOT: Execute command on remote server returning exit 2 instead of expected 0

Tags: robotframework

See below code. For some reason, the command ran on last line is returning an exit code of 2 from running in ROBOT. However, the command if ran manually will run ok (exit 0). Can you advise why this may be?

```
Open Connection     ${ENV_NAME}.XXX.com
Login With Public Key    ${username}  ../.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Put File  ${BATCH_FILE}  /var/tmp
Execute Command   mv /var/tmp/${FILE} ${files_to_process_path}
Close All Connections
Open Connection     ${ENV_NAME}.XXX.com
Login With Public Key    ${username}  ../.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Execute Command  pwd
Execute Command  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake RAILS_ENV=production longboat:process_patient_data_feed_01 search_folder=${path}to_process processed_folder=${path}processed failed_folder=${path}failed
```

Comment: Are you sure when you run it manually, you are *not* in the directory - like your script isn't? rake can be a bit wayward if the CWD is not the app's root one.

Comment: Ive added in a command where he cd's into the appropriate directory and then does ls. The latter command returns nothing (even though that dir has contents). Im wondering if we lose the connection at some stage or if it has a limited time span.

Comment: this is because every "Execute Command" creates new shell. So you have to bundle commands like "cd /some/dir/ && ls". Problem can occur due to some variables loaded from .bash_profile (or .bashrc, but I'm not sure if this one actually isn't loaded by default) file. So check smthing like: "Execute Command     source ~/.bash_profile && /usr/local/rvm...."